# Has more smiple solution to pass params to 3 fragments without create 3 bundles?

Tags: android

Fragment that create another 3 fragments:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY, "order1");
fragment1 = new MyFragmentSort();
fragment1.setArguments(args);

Bundle args2 = new Bundle();
args2.putString(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY, "order2");
fragment2 = new MyFragmentSort();
fragment2.setArguments(args2);

Bundle args3 = new Bundle();
args3.putString(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY, "order3");
fragment3 = new MyFragmentSort();
fragment3.setArguments(args3);
```

and then I add this 3 fragment to `FragmentPagerAdapter`

```
 private void setupViewPager(CustomViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(fragment1, "title1");
        adapter.addFragment(fragment2, "title2");
        adapter.addFragment(fragment3, "title3");
        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

OK. It's work.

But the qustion is:
Has more smiple solution to pass params to 3 fragments without create 3 **bundles**?

Comment: That's the best way to do it. What's the problem with creating 3 Bundles? The loss of speed and memory is minimal.

Comment: Too much code for so simple task

Comment: That's how Android API is designed, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the values in the Bundle are different, you need to create 3 bundles.

If your problem is the amount of code, then just create a simple function:

```
public static Bundle createOneEntryBundle(String key, String value) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(key, value);
    return bundle;
}
```

Your code will be a bit more compact:

```
fragment1 = new MyFragmentSort();
fragment1.setArguments(createOneEntryBundle(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY, "order1"));

fragment2 = new MyFragmentSort();
fragment2.setArguments(createOneEntryBundle(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY, "order2"));

fragment3 = new MyFragmentSort();
fragment3.setArguments(createOneEntryBundle(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY, "order3"));
```

Comment: @AbdulWaheed if your problem is the amount of code needed for the task, just create a simple function, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to create new  bundle in your case. Just replace the string every time and done. As shown in below code

```
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY, "order1");

    Log.d("test", args.getString(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY));

    args.putString(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY, "order2");

    Log.d("test", args.getString(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY));

    args.putString(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY, "order3");

    Log.d("test", args.getString(MyFragmentSort.ORDER_BY));
```

I have tested it. you must give it a try

Comment: This might cause concurrency issues, e.g. one fragment has not processed the bundle yet but you have already overwritten the value. And why are you using error level logging for debugging?

Comment: It's not help. Because all 3 fragments use last set value = "order3", But I need 3 different values for every fragments.